# Images don't load when first run

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use Android Universal Image Loader, and that is great library. But sometimes, when i open my app, images couldn't be loaded. I have to scroll down and then up to load images. What must i do to overcome this problem?

UIL version : `1.8.6`

Android version tested on  :    `4.1.2 (Galaxy S3)`

My configuration

```
config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            mContext).memoryCacheSize(Constants.MEM_CACHE_SIZE)
            .discCacheSize(Constants.DISC_CACHE_SIZE)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()).build();
```

Display options

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.empty_video)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_video)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.empty_video).cacheInMemory(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .delayBeforeLoading(500)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500))
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following in your ImageLoaderConfiguration:

```
.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
```

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately, my problem still occurs.

Comment: @MertŞimşek, just like to suggest to disable to image effect and try, //.delayBeforeLoading(500).displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500)),